# How to retrive data in a ArrayList using data in BasicDBObject?

Tags: java, mongodb, mongo-java

I have an object predictorObj, it contains data like: **{ "name" : "mpg" , "type" : "double"}**

static BasicDBObject predictorObj;

And I've an ArrayList object profile: The profile contains information like

```
{
  "MessageStatus": 2,
  "Origin": 2.0,
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "596340fc8b0fa35d2880d9a7"
  },
  "accerlation": 17.5,
  "cylinders": 4.0,
  "displacement": 110.0,
  "file_id": {
    "$oid": "59633e48b760e7c8071a6c1c"
  },
  "horsepower": 87.0,
  "message_status": 2,
  "modelyear": 70.0,
  "modified_date": {
    "$date": "2017-07-10T08:47:01.641Z"
  },
  "mpg": 25.0,
  "snet_id": "new_project",
  "unique_id": "413",
  "username": "peugeot 504",
  "weight": 2672.0
}
{
  "MessageStatus": 2,
  "Origin": 3.0,
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "596340fc8b0fa35d2880d9a5"
  },
  "accerlation": 14.5,
  "cylinders": 4.0,
  "displacement": 97.0,
  "file_id": {
    "$oid": "59633e48b760e7c8071a6c1c"
  },
  "horsepower": 88.0,
  "message_status": 2,
  "modelyear": 70.0,
  "modified_date": {
    "$date": "2017-07-10T08:47:01.641Z"
  },
  "mpg": 27.0,
  "snet_id": "new_project",
  "unique_id": "411",
  "username": "datsun pl510",
  "weight": 2130.0
}
{
  "MessageStatus": 2,
  "Origin": 1.0,
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "596340fc8b0fa35d2880d9a4"
  },
  "accerlation": 16.0,
  "cylinders": 6.0,
  "displacement": 200.0,
  "file_id": {
    "$oid": "59633e48b760e7c8071a6c1c"
  },
  "horsepower": 85.0,
  "message_status": 2,
  "modelyear": 70.0,
  "modified_date": {
    "$date": "2017-07-10T08:47:01.641Z"
  },
  "mpg": 21.0,
  "snet_id": "new_project",
  "unique_id": "410",
  "username": "ford maverick",
  "weight": 2587.0
}
{
  "MessageStatus": 2,
  "Origin": 1.0,
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "596340fc8b0fa35d2880d9a3"
  },
  "accerlation": 15.5,
  "cylinders": 6.0,
  "displacement": 199.0,
  "file_id": {
    "$oid": "59633e48b760e7c8071a6c1c"
  },
  "horsepower": 97.0,
  "message_status": 2,
  "modelyear": 70.0,
  "modified_date": {
    "$date": "2017-07-10T08:47:01.641Z"
  },
  "mpg": 18.0,
  "snet_id": "new_project",
  "unique_id": "409",
  "username": "amc hornet",
  "weight": 2774.0
}
{
  "MessageStatus": 2,
  "Origin": 1.0,
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "596340fc8b0fa35d2880d997"
  },
  "accerlation": 10.5,
  "cylinders": 8.0,
  "displacement": 302.0,
  "file_id": {
    "$oid": "59633e48b760e7c8071a6c1c"
  },
  "horsepower": 140.0,
  "message_status": 2,
  "modelyear": 70.0,
  "modified_date": {
    "$date": "2017-07-10T08:47:01.641Z"
  },
  "mpg": 17.0,
  "snet_id": "new_project",
  "unique_id": "397",
  "username": "ford torino",
  "weight": 3449.0
}
{
  "MessageStatus": 2,
  "Origin": 1.0,
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "596340fc8b0fa35d2880d996"
  },
  "accerlation": 12.0,
  "cylinders": 8.0,
  "displacement": 304.0,
  "file_id": {
    "$oid": "59633e48b760e7c8071a6c1c"
  },
  "horsepower": 150.0,
  "message_status": 2,
  "modelyear": 70.0,
  "modified_date": {
    "$date": "2017-07-10T08:47:01.641Z"
  },
  "mpg": 16.0,
  "snet_id": "new_project",
  "unique_id": "396",
  "username": "amc rebel sst",
  "weight": 3433.0
}
{
  "MessageStatus": 2,
  "Origin": 1.0,
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "596340fc8b0fa35d2880d992"
  },
  "accerlation": 19.4,
  "cylinders": 4.0,
  "displacement": 119.0,
  "file_id": {
    "$oid": "59633e48b760e7c8071a6c1c"
  },
  "horsepower": 82.0,
  "message_status": 2,
  "modelyear": 82.0,
  "modified_date": {
    "$date": "2017-07-10T08:47:01.641Z"
  },
  "mpg": 31.0,
  "snet_id": "new_project",
  "unique_id": "392",
  "username": "chevy s-10",
  "weight": 2720.0
}
{
  "MessageStatus": 2,
  "Origin": 1.0,
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "596340fc8b0fa35d2880d991"
  },
  "accerlation": 18.6,
  "cylinders": 4.0,
  "displacement": 120.0,
  "file_id": {
    "$oid": "59633e48b760e7c8071a6c1c"
  },
  "horsepower": 79.0,
  "message_status": 2,
  "modelyear": 82.0,
  "modified_date": {
    "$date": "2017-07-10T08:47:01.641Z"
  },
  "mpg": 28.0,
  "snet_id": "new_project",
  "unique_id": "391",
  "username": "ford ranger",
  "weight": 2625.0
}
{
  "MessageStatus": 2,
  "Origin": 1.0,
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "596340fc8b0fa35d2880d990"
  },
  "accerlation": 11.6,
  "cylinders": 4.0,
  "displacement": 135.0,
  "file_id": {
    "$oid": "59633e48b760e7c8071a6c1c"
  },
  "horsepower": 84.0,
  "message_status": 2,
  "modelyear": 82.0,
  "modified_date": {
    "$date": "2017-07-10T08:47:01.641Z"
  },
  "mpg": 32.0,
  "snet_id": "new_project",
  "unique_id": "390",
  "username": "dodge rampage",
  "weight": 2295.0
}
{
  "MessageStatus": 2,
  "Origin": 2.0,
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "596340fc8b0fa35d2880d98f"
  },
  "accerlation": 24.6,
  "cylinders": 4.0,
  "displacement": 97.0,
  "file_id": {
    "$oid": "59633e48b760e7c8071a6c1c"
  },
  "horsepower": 52.0,
  "message_status": 2,
  "modelyear": 82.0,
  "modified_date": {
    "$date": "2017-07-10T08:47:01.641Z"
  },
  "mpg": 44.0,
  "snet_id": "new_project",
  "unique_id": "389",
  "username": "vw pickup",
  "weight": 2130.0
}
{
  "MessageStatus": 2,
  "Origin": 1.0,
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "596340fc8b0fa35d2880d98a"
  },
  "accerlation": 14.7,
  "cylinders": 6.0,
  "displacement": 232.0,
  "file_id": {
    "$oid": "59633e48b760e7c8071a6c1c"
  },
  "horsepower": 112.0,
  "message_status": 2,
  "modelyear": 82.0,
  "modified_date": {
    "$date": "2017-07-10T08:47:01.641Z"
  },
  "mpg": 22.0,
  "snet_id": "new_project",
  "unique_id": "384",
  "username": "ford granada l",
  "weight": 2835.0
}
{
  "MessageStatus": 2,
  "Origin": 3.0,
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "596340fc8b0fa35d2880d986"
  },
  "accerlation": 16.2,
  "cylinders": 4.0,
  "displacement": 91.0,
  "file_id": {
    "$oid": "59633e48b760e7c8071a6c1c"
  },
  "horsepower": 67.0,
  "message_status": 2,
  "modelyear": 82.0,
  "modified_date": {
    "$date": "2017-07-10T08:47:01.641Z"
  },
  "mpg": 38.0,
  "snet_id": "new_project",
  "unique_id": "380",
  "username": "datsun 310 gx",
  "weight": 1995.0
}
```

Now I want to retrieve the data from profile which is matching to predictor objject.

Can anyone help?

Comment: What value of mpg you would like to retrieve? It should be some double value like 25.0 etc. Otherwise, we can't match or filter the document.

Comment: my predictorObj contains 2 fields name & type and my list object contains above mentioned data.

Comment: But the type contains value as double. Do you mean it is double value like 25.0?

Comment: Yes@notionquest

Comment: I want to map the data in predictorObj with profile data, whatever the fields in the profile matches with predictorObj then I want to collect all that information and store into a collection object. Ex: List<...> x = new ArrayList<...>; x would contain: {"mpg":{18.0,25.0,29.0...etc}}

Comment: I want to map the data in predictorObj with profile data, whatever the fields in the profile matches with predictorObj then I want to collect all that information and store into a collection object. Ex: List<...> x = new ArrayList<...>; x would contain: {"mpg":{18.0,25.0,29.0...etc}}